# plugin that auto img's height got an EXAMPLE

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I am looking for plugin that arrange the images like that:
http://milli.wpengine.com/

I have trying to do that but I have not succsed...

http://build-net.co.il/aba/

Thanks guys.

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a jQuery plugin like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html), which allows you to stack images like that or as it's probably more commonly known for being used on: Pinterest.

Comment: maybe you know why some images hide behind other images.


http://asher-gallery.com/
if its look ok try to refresh the page.